# Connecting Raspberry Pi 3 B to Android 4G hotspot

Tags: pi-3, wifi, hotspot

First off, let me explain, I'm completely new to the Raspberry world and Linux commands.  Heck, I haven't even bought a Raspberry yet. (very green)  I'm into coding web applications (Java, PHP, HTML), so I'm pretty sure I'll be fine with the technical side of things, if explained to me.  I'm just not a code junkie.

I'm getting fed up paying my cable company $170 a month for TV and internet.  A friend at work mentioned the Raspberry Pi running Kodi as a way to cut the cable cord, so to speak.

I use Verizon wireless as my cell phone carrier and I have their unlimited data plan ( paid through work :-} ).  I am currently using the Moto Z2 Play.  I get a great 4G signal at my house.

So, I started wondering if I could drop both internet and TV and just use the hotpost on my phone to fulfill all the media needs.

So, before I invest in a Raspberry Pi, I'd like to know if anyone here has connected their Raspberry Pi 3 B to their 4G cell data?  If so, is it something you'd recommend quality wise?

Additionally, to connect to the hotspot would I just us the GUI OS or would it require command line?  If command line is required could you share details?

Comment: The only problem is before you drop your internet, you should see how fast your 4G can get upto. Also other things to consider are, is the phone going to be plugged in all the time? Will it be able to handle many devices connected to it at the same time? Will the speed be fast enough?

Comment: @Darkest Good point.  I have good signal in my house but I'm not 100% sure on the speed it gets.  I would only have 1 device connected (the raspberry pi) at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two things to consider:

- **Quality of media streaming** I've been in situations where I've needed internet access on my laptop and didn't have access to either ethernet or WiFi. I've setup a hotspot on my phone and had my laptop connect to it, and boy was it ever horrible. I wasn't streaming media, all I was doing was accessing a simple text website. If you have a laptop, try it, you will see if the quality is to your liking.
- **Can it handle all your internet needs** Your phone is a phone. It's not a router. It doesn't have the broadcast power to have the range or number of connections that a router can. Again, try it with a few devices, maybe get a friend to bring their laptop over and see what happens when 2 of you connect to the hotspot at the same time and stream content.